# Determine the limit using Taylor expansions:

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I struggle with this one—maybe someone could point me in the right direction.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{5^{(1+\tan^2x)} -5}{1-\cos^2x}$$

Getting the Taylor series expansion for $\tan^2x$ and $\sin^2x$ is no problem, but I struggle with getting further along at this step:

$$\frac{5^1 \cdot 5^{x^2} \cdot 5^{(2/3)x^4} -5}{x^2 - \frac{x^4}3}$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, I saw the sin^2 but not the sec^2, but still, concerning the taylor expansion, they are the same and I arrive at the same problem again.

Comment: Just to be clear, did you mean to write $5(1+\tan^{2}(x))-5$ or $5^{1+\tan^{2}(x)} -5$ in the numerator?

Comment: Thank you for the request for clarification, I tried to write the second one but it did not turn out as well as yours, I'll try to edit it with your code!

Comment: Do you need to use the Taylor expansions? L'Hôpital's rule will get you the answer pretty quickly.

Comment: True, but unfortunately, yes, Taylor expansions are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $\exp(x)=1+x+O(x^2)$ and $\tan^{2}(x) = x^{2}+O(x^{4})$
\begin{align*}5^{\tan^{2}(x)} &=\exp(\ln(5)\tan^{2}(x))\\
&=\exp(\ln(5)(x^2+O(x^4)))\\
&=1+\ln(5)(x^2+O(x^{4}))+ O([x^2+O(x^{4})]^2)\\
&=1+\ln(5)x^{2}+O(x^{4})
\end{align*}

Therefore, using $1-\cos^{2}(x)=x^{2}+O(x^{4})$:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{5(5^{\tan^{2}(x)}-1)}{1-\cos^{2}(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}5\frac{1+\ln(5)x^2+O(x^4)-1}{x^{2}+O(x^{4})}$$
I am sure you can take it from here

Comment: Mille grazie, very elegant and concise!

Answer (score 3):

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{5^{1+\tan^2(x)}-5}{1-\cos^2(x)}=$

$=5\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{5^{\tan^2(x)}-1}{\sin^2(x)}=$

$=5\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left[\dfrac{5^{\tan^2(x)}-1}{\tan^2(x)}\cdot\dfrac1{\cos^2(x)}\right]=$

$=5\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{5^{\tan^2(x)}-1}{\tan^2(x)}\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac1{\cos^2(x)}\underset{\overbrace{\text{by letting }y=\tan^2(x)}}{=}$

$=5\lim\limits_{y\to0}\dfrac{5^y-1}y\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac1{\cos^2(x)}=$

$=5\cdot\ln5\cdot1=$

$=5\ln5\;.$

**Addendum :**

If you want to calculate the limit by using Taylor expansions, you can proceed in the following way :

$\dfrac{5^{1+\tan^2(x)}-5}{1-\cos^2(x)}=$

$=5\cdot\dfrac{5^{\tan^2(x)}-1}{\sin^2(x)}=$

$=5\cdot\dfrac{5^{\tan^2(x)}-1}{\tan^2(x)}\cdot\dfrac1{\cos^2(x)}\underset{\overbrace{\text{by letting }y=\tan^2(x)}}{=}$

$=5\cdot\dfrac{5^y-1}y\cdot\dfrac1{\cos^2(x)}=$

$=5\ln5\cdot\dfrac{e^{y\ln5}-1}{y\ln5}\cdot\dfrac1{\cos^2(x)}=$

$=5\ln5\cdot\dfrac{y\ln5+\frac{(y\ln5)^2}2+O(y^3)}{y\ln5}\cdot\dfrac1{\left(1-\frac{x^2}2+O(x^4)\right)^2}=$

$=5\ln5\cdot\dfrac{1+\frac{y\ln5}2+O(y^2)}{1-x^2+O(x^4)}\xrightarrow{\color{blue}{x\to0}}5\ln5\;.$

It is not necessary to write only Taylor expansions in powers of $x$, we can also write a Taylor expansion in powers of $y$ which is an infinitesimal function of $x$ as $x\to0\;.$

Comment: This is not the answer because the question explicitly asks Taylor.

Comment: Look at my addendum.

Comment: It is not necessary to write only Taylor expansions in powers of $x$, we can also write a Taylor expansion in powers of $y$ which is an infinitesimal function of $x$ as $x\to0\;.$

Comment: Thank you, also a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} 5 \ln(5) + 5/2 x^2 \ln (5) (2 + \ln (5)) + O(x^4)= 5 \ln(5)$$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+%5Cfrac%7B5%5E%7B%281%2B%5Ctan%5E2%28x%29%29%7D+-5%7D%7B1-%5Ccos%5E2%28x%29%7D